# How to use google suggest api with java application

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-suggest

I want to use the google-suggest-api in my Java application.

Can i call `http://google.com/complete/search?q=Test&output=toolbar` via a Java application?

Please give me an example.

Updated.

Below code is work in my java application but when I use in java servlet (apache tomcat 6.0 is my web server) it return result without suggest content "< ?xml version="1.0"?>< toplevel/>"  why?

private void getSuggestWord(String keyword){

```
    try {
        String urlName = "http://google.com/complete/search?q=" + keyword + "&output=toolbar";
        System.out.println(urlName);
        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723                       Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can. 
Start reading about the [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), and see the examples there. 
In general what you need to do is - 
A. Create an HTTP connection 
B. Post your Requerst 
C. Read the result 
D. Parse the result